# groupby() with sort_values() - how to yield correct order of priority

Tags: python

I have this DF

```
    type    sub_type    price
0   bed     single      15
1   bed     double      25
2   chair   single      75
3   chair   double      105
4   couch   single      45
5   couch   double      95
```

This is the order of sum-total price by type

```
    type    price
0   chair   180
1   couch   140
2   bed     40
```

CURRENT OUTPUT - I am trying to have this reflected when I groupby() and sort_values() but I cannot stop it from sorting the 'type' name alphabetically - as follows

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['type','sub_type']).sum()['price'])
df_1.sort_values(['type', 'price'], ascending=False)

    

type    sub_type    price
couch     double    95
          single    45
chair     double    105
          single    75
bed       double    25
          single    15
```

DESIRED OUTPUT - chair and couch are in proper order based off of total price

```
type      sub_type  price
chair     double    105
          single    75
couch     double    95
          single    45
bed       double    25
          single    15
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.merge`:

```
q = df.groupby('type')['price'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index()
    
df_1 = pd.merge(q[['type']], df.sort_values('price', ascending=False), on='type')

print(df_1)
    type sub_type  price
0  chair   double    105
1  chair   single     75
2  couch   double     95
3  couch   single     45
4    bed   double     25
5    bed   single     15
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @ Rick M. that enabled me to do what I needed to do